# RpLidar A1 arduino

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm trying to connect RpLidar into Arduino Portenta H7 Lite and get the data into Robot Operating System. I trying to use to rplidar_arduino package to read data from lidar and next I'm using rosserial to pass data into ROS, but unfortunately I don't know how to pass it. Have anyone tried to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405317/rplidar-a1-arduino/) by [Heqas](https://answers.ros.org/users/113186/heqas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried at first with Arduino, but found it easier to connect it via USB directly to a Raspberry Pi or the PC your ROS is running, and using http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar

---

Originally posted by [Edyger](https://answers.ros.org/users/82461/edyger/) with karma: 36 on 2022-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2